# Manually iterating a line of a file | bash

Tags: bash, shell, loops, iteration

I could do this in any other language, but with Bash I've looked far and wide and could not find the answer.

I need to manually increase `$line` in a script. Example:

```
for line in `cat file`
do
foo()
       foo_loop(condition)
{
 do_something_to_line($line) 
}
done
```

If you notice, every time the `foo_loop` iterates, `$line` stays the same. I need to iterate `$line` there, and make sure the original for loop only runs the number of lines in file.

I have thought about finding the number of lines in file using a different loop and iterating the line variable inside the inner loop of `foo()`.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Sorry for being so vague.

Here we go:

I'm trying to make a section of my code execute multiple times (parallel execution)

```
Function foo() # Does something
for line in `cat $temp_file`;
foo($line)
```

That code works just fine, because `foo` is just taking in the value of line; *but* if I wanted to do this:

```
Function foo() # Does something
for line in `cat $temp_file`;
while (some condition)
foo($line)
end
```

`$line` will equal the same value throughout the while loop. I need it to change with the `while` loop, then continue when it goes back to the `for`. Example:

```
line = Hi
foo{ echo "$line" }; 
for line in `cat file`;
while ( number_of_processes_running -lt max_number_allowed)
foo($line)
end
```

If the contents of file were

```
Hi \n Bye \n Yellow \n Green \n
```

The output of the example program would be (if max number allowed was 3)

```
Hi Hi Hi Bye Bye Bye Yellow Yellow Yellow Green Green Green.
```

Where I want it to be

```
Hi Bye Yellow Green
```

I hope this is better. I'm doing my best to explain my problem.

Comment: I think we need a clearer example of what you're trying to accomplish. foo() appears to define a shell function within a loop, which I'm not sure is what you want.

Answer (score 16):

Instead of using a for loop to read through the file you should maybe read through the file like so.

```
#!bin/bash

while read line
do
    do_something_to_line($line)
done < "your.file"
```

Comment: Note that this will not quite work for lines with backslashes (read removes them) and leading and/or trailing whitespace (removed as well). The proper way is to use `read -r line` to avoid the backslash removal and to set `IFS=` to avoid the whitespace removal.

Answer (score 6):

Long story short, `while read line; do _____ ; done`

Then, make sure you have double-quotes around "$line" so that a parameter isn't delimited by spaces.

Example:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | md5sum
c2eb5696e59948852f66a82993016e5a *-

$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | while read line; do echo "$line"; done | md5sum
c2eb5696e59948852f66a82993016e5a *-
```

Second example 
    # add .gz to every file in the current directory:
    # If any files had spaces, the mv command for that line would return an error.

```
$ find -type f -maxdepth 1 | while read line; do mv "$line" "$line.gz"; done
```

Comment: -1 for the useless use of cat. Did you know you can redirect into compound commands as well? `while read ...; do ...; done < file` works.

Answer (score 1):

You should post follow-ups as edits to your question or in comments rather than as an answer.

This structure:

```
while read line
do
    for (( i=1; i<$max_number_allowed; i++ ))
    do
        foo $line
    done
done < file
```

Yields:

```
Hi
Hi
Hi
Bye
Bye
Bye
...etc.
```

While this one:

```
for (( i=1; i<$max_number_allowed; i++ ))
do
    while read line
    do
        foo $line
    done < file
done
```

Yields:

```
Hi
Bye
Yellow
Green
Hi
Bye
Yellow
Green
...etc.
```